# Characterization of convergence in Baire Space under the chosen metric function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, set-theory

Let $X$ be a infinite set and consider $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$. The metric function is defined for $f, g \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ as $0$ if $f = g$ and $\frac{1}{\min [ k \in \mathbb{N}: f(k) \neq g(k) ] }$ if $f \neq g$.

Let $f_k \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence, it is required to prove that if
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \Big(m \ge N \longrightarrow f_N(i) = f_m(i)\Big), \quad 1 \le i \le n, \quad (*)$$
then $f_k \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $g \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$, that is,
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \Big(m \ge N \longrightarrow d(f_m, g) < \epsilon \Big), \quad (**)$$

What has been tried is the following:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By the Archimedean Property, there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{\epsilon} < n_0$. Thus, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$, if $m \ge N$, then $f_N(i) = f_m(i)$, for $1 \le i \le n_0$.

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and by hypothesis in $(**)$, since $m \ge N$, $f_N(i) = f_m(i)$, for $1 \le i \le n_0$.

EDIT 1:

If $f_N(i) = f_m(i)$, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $d(f_N, f_m) = 0 < \epsilon$, for $m \ge N$.

If $f_N \neq f_m$, then for some $n_0 < k_0$, $f_N(k_0) \neq f_m(k_0)$. By the Well-Ordering Principle, suppose that $k_0$ is the minimum natural such that $f_N(k_0) \neq f_m(k_0)$. Thus, $d(f_N, f_m) = \frac{1}{k_0}$.

Since $n_0 < k_0$, $\frac{1}{k_0} < \frac{1}{n_0}$. Thus,
$$d(f_N, f_m) = \frac{1}{k_0} < \frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$$
for $m \ge N$.

Therefore, $f_k \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f_N$, which is well-defined since $N \in \mathbb{N}$ was a fixed element provided by the hypothesis in $(*)$.

Is the proof correct? There is skepticism about it.